# Neo4j APOC Export CSV to specific Directory

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Following query works fine for me

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query("MATCH (a:Person)
RETURN a.name AS name", "result.csv", {})
```

but i want to export the result to a specific directory e.g in 'test' directory `/neo4j-community-3.2.6/test/result.csv`

Test directory exists in neo4j-community-3.2.6 folder, but the query

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query("
    MATCH (a:Person)
    RETURN a.name AS name",
"/test/result.csv", {})
```

gives me following error:

> Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed Failed to invoke
>   procedure `apoc.export.csv.query`: Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: \test\result.csv (The system cannot
>   find the path specified)

Can any one help?

Comment: The first query is putting the file in what directory?

Comment: Thanks for your response. It was putting the result.csv in /neo4j-community-3.2.6 directory. And i wanted to put into a sub-directory neo4j-community-3.2.6/test

Comment: See also this [related issue](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/609) about relative paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is resolved. I got help from "neo4j-users.slack.com" by user "tomasi".
For this we need to provide the complete path in the parameter:

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query("MATCH (a:Person)
    RETURN a.name AS name",
"/home/xyzuser/neo4j-community-3.2.6/test/result.csv", {})
```

Answer (score 0):

The files are saved  in bin folder by default.
Give file location as '../test/result.csv' might work.
Worked in my case